# Best of MathOverflow, or papers inspired by MathOverflow

Tags: discussion, faq, site-promotion

This is a place to collect MathOverflow success stories!

Was some of your research inspired by something on MathOverflow? Do you know questions & answers that led to interesting research? MathOverflow citations? Open problems solved on MathOverflow? Then add your story in an answer! (One story per answer, please!)

If you want to help get this thread started, you can [use this search](http://search.arxiv.org:8081/?query=%22math+overflow%22+OR+mathoverflow&in=grp_math) to find MathOverflow citations on the arXiv or migrate some old stories from [tea.mathoverflow.net](http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/64/where-to-keep-track-of-mathoverflow-success-stories/).

Comment: This question was suggested in [this discussion](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/563/where-to-share-mathoverflow-success-stories).

Comment: Is it really the case that the old success stories have to be migrated by hand? I'm surprised there's not a way to do this within the stack software or at least write a program to do it.

Comment: @David: Clarify what you're suggesting. What do you propose migrating this way?

Comment: Hi. I felt that if we plan to have a single unified place for success stories (e.g. if someone wants to come and write an article about MO) then it doesn't make sense to have one place at tea for pre-migration and one here for post-migration. So the old success stories should be here, since it appears we can't add new ones to that old page. But it would take a long time to move them over one by one. I wish it could be done all at once.

Comment: @David: The thread at tea is mostly other stuff so it's best to do it manually.

Comment: @DavidWhite tangentially, but one could add things in the old thread.

Comment: Many papers were inspired by questions raised on MO, but has any credit been given to those who raised the questions in the publications? I am just wondering.

Comment: @qed I know for a fact that in many instances, perhaps most, the MO question-asker is given credit and citations. Further, I know of several cases, and I expect that there are many more, in which the question-asker was invited to join as co-author.

Comment: I wonder if the title should be changed from "Best of MathOverflow" to "Publications resulting from MathOverflow" (or maybe "inspired by"?). It has in fact developed into publication citing.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke What you write is perhaps true. OTOH the ones which MO community considers the best are quite likely to rise to the top based on voting, so in this sense it might still be a fitting title. I'll point out that Todd Trimble recently [commented on the title of this thread](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2018/1/21): *Some people might feel uneasy citing their own work at a thread entitled "Best of MathOverflow", but perhaps that title should be interpreted broadly*

Comment: This is sort of a duplicate of this closed question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/11846/1345

Comment: @Ian I think the idea was that meta is a more appropriate place for this question than main was.

Comment: As the link to tea given at the end of the post [does not work now](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4438), I'll add a [link to Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20190726172226/http://mathoverflow.tqft.net/discussion/64/where-to-keep-track-of-mathoverflow-success-stories/) at least here in a comment.

Comment: I'd like to shorten the current title *"Best of MathOverflow, or papers inspired by MathOverflow"* to *"Research inspired by MathOverflow"*. Two reasons: one is that I'd feel uncomfortable in claiming a paper (especially mine) as "best of". Second, it just better suits the question. (In practice it's rather "Papers inspired by MO", but the question allows a broader interpretation.) What do you think?

Answer (score 47):

[Mark Sapir](https://mathoverflow.net/users/6976/mark-sapir) solved an interesting open problem in group theory in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/137715) to a [question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/137678) of [Narutaka OZAWA](https://mathoverflow.net/users/7591/narutaka-ozawa).

Answer (score 43):

In April 2013 I discussed with Alan Sokal the following conjecture: if $P$ is a real polynomial with the property $|P(z)|<P(|z|)$ then some power of $P$ has positive coefficients.
We did not prove it at that time.

In August, Ofer Zeitouni asked on MO to describe all possible limits of the so-called empirical measures of polynomials with positive coefficients. He needed this for his research
on random polynomials. It immediately crossed my mind, that
a proof of the Sokal's conjecture stated above will imply the answer to Zeitouni's question.

The final result was a paper by Walter Bergweiler, Alan Sokal and myself,
[https://www.math.purdue.edu/~eremenko/newprep.html](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Eeremenko/newprep.html)
where we prove the a necessary and sufficient conditions on a real polynomial for some
power of it to have positive coefficients, and give an answer to Zeitouni's question.
[Zeros of polynomials with real positive coefficients](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134998/zeros-of-polynomials-with-real-positive-coefficients/136099#136099)

Edit. This story has a continuation, also related to MO.
[Another related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/180455/stability-of-real-polynomials-with-positive-coefficients/180493#180493) was asked on MO, and one of the answers contained a reference to a published proof of what I called "Sokal conjecture". It was essentially the same as our proof. So the net outcome was only a paper answering Zeitouni's question.

Comment: In turn, that answer (and the methods in the paper) will be used by Subhro Ghosh and I in a forthcoming work, which we hope to post soon.

Answer (score 42):

Our article [D. Brumleve, J. D. Hamkins, and P. Schlicht, “The mate-in-n problem of infinite chess is decidable,” LNCS 7318(2012):78-88](http://jdh.hamkins.org/the-mate-in-n-problem-of-infinite-chess-is-decidable/), [arXiv:1201.5597](https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.5597), was inspired directly by Richard Stanley's question [Decidability of chess on an infinite board](https://mathoverflow.net/a/86755/1946).

**Abstract.** Infinite chess is chess played on an infinite edgeless chessboard. The familiar chess pieces move about according to their usual chess rules, and each player strives to place the opposing king into checkmate. The mate-in-n problem of infinite chess is the problem of determining whether a designated player can force a win from a given finite position in at most n moves. The main theorem of this article, confirming a conjecture of the second author and C. D. A. Evans, establishes that the mate-in-n problem of infinite chess is computably decidable, uniformly in the position and in n. The proof proceeds by showing that the mate-in-n problem is expressible in what we call the first-order structure of chess, which we prove (in the relevant fragment) is an automatic structure, whose theory is therefore decidable. An alternative argument proceeds via Presburger arithmetic, which is capable of interpreting the mate-in-n problem of infinite chess.

(This was a collaboration truly born on MathOverflow, as some of the authors have never met in person...)

Comment: Is Richard Stanley also a collaborator to the article?

Comment: No; we cite his question, but he is not a co-author or collaborator.

Comment: And by that, your definition of "collaborator" refers to?

Comment: I had meant the ordinary meaning of "collaborator." In mathematical research, this would be someone with whom you work together on a research project, making a joint intellectual effort. Here is a list of my own research collaborators: http://jdh.hamkins.org/collaborators/

Comment: So is it basically just a place where you thank people for helping? Is a "collaborator" an objective thing or is it totally subjective and you can list anyone you wanted that had helped you *tangentially*? What would be the bare minimum to qualify for a "collaborator"?

Comment: I would refer you to a dictionary or to english.stackexchange.com for advice on use of the word "collaborator."

Comment: I actually mean.. is it a *specific terminology* used in maths research?

Answer (score 41):

A meta-answer: http://search.arxiv.org:8081/?query=mathoverflow&in= returns a list of 197 papers on the arXiv which mention MathOverflow.

Nearly all of these are actual citations, with a small number of papers about MathOverflow itself, and some number of papers which mention MathOverflow without giving full attribution according to the guidelines.

Perhaps at some point it would be interesting to analyze this full collection (which is clearly a significant superset of the things mentioned in other answers here).

Comment: This is incomplete. The query does not return http://arxiv.org/abs/1302.1659v2, which mentions MO.

Comment: The issue there seems to be that MO is only mentioned in a URL, so "mathoverflow" is not found as a word by the search.  There are probably others which insert a space, as in "Math Overflow" and are similarly missed, but I can't get arXiv search to work for me right now to check.

Comment: It is great to have your query, but we should recognize that not probably not every citation of MathOverflow rises to the level of a "success story". At least some of the papers arising in your query, for example, including some of my own papers there, are just making a small citation about a minor matter. So perhaps we should interpret the question as asking for instances of work that is more deeply connected with or inspired by something on MathOverflow.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, agreed, perhaps I should have mentioned this search URL somewhere else.

Comment: Oh, I think it is fine here (and a similar query was mentioned already in the question).

Comment: Hmmm, this is weird - four year laters, that list has increased to 201, which seems to me to be a much lower increment than you'd expect. So maybe that search is missing some important bits.

Answer (score 38):

This is an old and self-indulgent story; but it was such a charmingly unexpected bonus from my early use of MathOverflow, that I think it deserves to be recorded somewhere (my apologies for its length!):

tl;dr: As a serendipitous consequence of [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/16105/492), the second answerer invited me to give my first-ever seminar talk as a grad student.

At the time I was a 2nd year grad student in topology, working on a project related to [knot signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_of_a_knot). Specifically, I was hoping to relate [this paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=TWISTED%20ALEXANDER%20INVARIANTS%2C%20REIDEMEISTER%20TORSION%2C%20AND%20CASSON%E2%80%93GORDON%20INVARIANTS&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C33&as_sdtp=) by Kirk and Livingston to some possibly novel computations I'd made, but I was having some basic difficulties, leading to [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/16105/492). My question didn't mention the paper, since my confusion was quite preliminary to its content. In addition to a great answer by Emerton, I got [another great answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/16118/492) from a mysterious user "Paul." In an illuminating response to my follow-up comment, Paul even mentioned the paper I'd been reading! In my surprised reply, I explained that this paper was in fact directly responsible for my question.

Paul eventually revealed by email that in a miraculous coincidence, he was in fact P. Kirk, one of the authors of that original, motivating paper! (This possibility had certainly never occurred to me). After more email exchanges, and more due to his kindness than my results, Paul actually invited me to talk in the Bloomington topology seminar, to discuss things in person. This led to my [first ever "invited" seminar talk](http://www.math.indiana.edu/seminars/event.phtml?id=2961) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20161204163435/http://www.math.indiana.edu/seminars/event.phtml?id=2961)), and a truly fantastic visit to Bloomington, very formative as well as informative!

My computations themselves were never actually published, but they did make it into my thesis, [which is on the arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.0769) (Chapter 3). This story, however, is not in my thesis! I'm glad I could record it somewhere. Please edit if appropriate!

Comment: Why not link to your thesis on the arXiv?

Comment: good point, done! for some reason, when I wrote the post, it felt too self-indulgent to promote my thesis as well ;)

Comment: This is a great success story, and also points out one of the advantages of using real names on MO. When I can identify a poster to be a motivated student I am much more likely to go out of my way to be helpful than if the OP is anonymous.

Answer (score 33):

Ben Green's [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1103.4991) on (not) computing the Möbius function arose from [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57543/walsh-fourier-transform-of-mobius-functions) on MathOverflow.

**Abstract.** Any function $F : \{1,\dots,N\} \rightarrow \{-1,1\}$ such that $F(x)$ can be computed from the binary digits of $x$ using a bounded depth circuit is orthogonal to the Möbius function $\mu$ in the sense that $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{x \leq N} \mu(x)F(x) = o_{N \rightarrow \infty}(1)$. The proof combines a result of Linial, Mansour and Nisan with techniques of Kátai and Harman-Kátai, used in their work on finding primes with specified digits.

Answer (score 31):

The MO question

[Norms of Commutators](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27345/norms-of-commutators)

is referenced in a paper by Ozawa, Schechtman and me that will appear in the PNAS. [arXiv:1202.0986](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.0986)

Answer (score 27):

Tom Church, Melody Chan, and Joshua Grochow just posted their paper "Rotor-routing and spanning trees on planar graphs" to the arXiv [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.2677).  It answers [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83552/what-is-the-sandpile-torsor) MO question which was asked by Jordan Ellenberg.

Answer (score 24):

Our article, [C. D. A. Evans and J. D. Hamkins, Transfinite game values in infinite chess](http://jdh.hamkins.org/game-values-in-infinite-chess/), where we investigate the range of transfinite game values arising in infinite chess, grew directly out of Johan Wästlund's question [Checkmate in $\omega$ moves?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63423/checkmate-in-omega-moves/122250#122250).
In particular, we define the *omega one of chess* $\omega_1^{\frak{Ch}}$ to be the supremum of the ordinal game values that arise in the positions of infinite chess.

**Abstract.** In this article, we investigate the transfinite game values arising in infinite chess, providing both upper and lower bounds on the supremum of these values — the omega one of chess — denoted by $\omega_1^{\mathfrak{Ch}}$ in the context of finite positions and by $\omega_1^{\mathfrak{Ch}_{\!\!\!\!\sim}}$ in the context of all positions, including those with infinitely many pieces. For lower bounds, we present specific positions with transfinite game values of $\omega$, $\omega^2$, $\omega^2\cdot k$ and $\omega^3$. By embedding trees into chess, we show that there is a computable infinite chess position that is a win for white if the players are required to play according to a deterministic computable strategy, but which is a draw without that restriction. Finally, we prove that every countable ordinal arises as the game value of a position in infinite three-dimensional chess, and consequently the omega one of infinite three-dimensional chess is as large as it can be, namely, true $\omega_1$.

The article is 38 pages, with 18 figures detailing many interesting positions of infinite chess. My co-author Cory Evans holds the chess title of U.S. National Master.

Follow the links to see the chess positions, such as the following, which has value $\omega^2\cdot 4$.

[image]

Answer (score 23):

The paper [A Counterexample to a Conjecture of Schwartz](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~pds/papers/tourstable/paper.pdf) by Brandt, Chudnovsky, Kim, Liu, Norin, Scott, Seymour, and Thomassé answers this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9177/disjoint-stable-sets-in-tournaments) of Felix Brandt.  The question asks whether a weakened form of Schwartz’ Conjecture (a popular conjecture in Social Choice Theory) is true. The paper proves that even this weakened form of the conjecture is false, thus resolving Schwartz’ Conjecture in the negative.  I think this is a nice example where one area calls on the expertise of another, and the call is answered.

**Abstract.** 
In 1990, motivated by applications in the social sciences, Thomas Schwartz made a conjecture about
tournaments which would have had numerous attractive consequences. In particular, it implied that
there is no tournament with a partition $A, B$ of its vertex set, such that every transitive subset of $A$ is
in the out-neighbour set of some vertex in $B$, and vice versa. But in fact there is such a tournament,
as we show in this paper, and so Schwartz’ conjecture is false. Our proof is non-constructive and
uses the probabilistic method.

Comment: This is nice, but I am not sure how it qualifies: Brandt posted the question, so he was already thinking about it, and then Brandt and his collaborators solved it (perhaps because no other answer was suggested here).

Comment: As I understand it, the question was completely unknown to all the non-Brandt authors before the MO question.  I attended a talk by Ilhee Kim where he said that he saw the question on MO and started working on it.  He then told the problem to Paul Seymour (his PhD advisor), and then eventually many other people got involved and solved it.  So without MO, the problem would likely still be open.

Comment: Ah, great! I did not see them mentioning this in the paper, that would have been nice. Thank you!

Answer (score 22):

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.8192) (details below) by Zhen Lin Low and Aaron Mazel-Gee cites not just MO but:

> This collaboration would not have happened without the ‘Homotopy Theory’
> chat room on MathOverflow.

---

arXiv.org > math > arXiv:1409.8192

**From fractions to complete Segal spaces**

Zhen Lin Low, Aaron Mazel-Gee

We show that the Rezk classification diagram of a relative category admitting a homotopical version of the two-sided calculus of fractions is a Segal space up to Reedy-fibrant replacement. In particular, the Rezk classification diagram of a closed model category in the sense of Quillen is a complete Segal space up to Reedy-fibrant replacement, resolving a conjecture of Rezk.

Answer (score 21):

My MO question [Conjugation of group extensions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199410/conjugation-of-group-extensions) was answered by [YCor](https://mathoverflow.net/users/14094/ycor). As a result, we wrote a joint note
[Conjugate complex homogeneous spaces with non-isomorphic fundamental groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02323) published in C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris, Ser. I, 353 (2015) 1001–1005.

Comment: Congratulations! I think that this information should be added to the original MO question as well.

Answer (score 18):

This [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83161) was asked in December of 2011, in line with a reference request for a senior thesis on odd perfect numbers completed in 1978.  Subsequently, the OP has tried numerous ways to get hold of the thesis's author.

On August 24, 2013 [Jim (Condict) Grace](https://mathoverflow.net/users/39046) (the thesis's author) popped in to MO to respond to the original question.

Comment: I don't see how this qualifies as an answer to the question. It's not research inspired by something on MathOverflow; it's not a citation of MathOverflow; it's not an open problem solved on MathOverflow.

Comment: It's a success story, isn't it?

Answer (score 17):

My joint article with Justin Palumbo, [The rigid relation principle, a new weak choice principle](http://jdh.hamkins.org/therigidrelationprincipleanewweakacprinciple) (Mathematical Logic Quarterly 58(6):394-398, 2012) grew out of our answers to my question, [Does every set admit a rigid binary relation? (and how is this related to the Axiom of Choice?)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6262/does-every-set-admit-a-rigid-binary-relation-and-how-is-this-related-to-the-ax), which grew out of Mike Shulman's question, [A rigid type of structure that can be put on every set?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5920/a-rigid-type-of-structure-that-can-be-put-on-every-set), on which I had made my very first post upon coming here to MathOverflow.

**Abstract.** The *rigid relation principle* asserts that every set admits a rigid binary relation. This follows from the axiom of choice, because well-orders are rigid, but we prove that it is neither equivalent to the axiom of choice nor provable in Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory without the axiom of choice. Thus, it is a new weak choice principle. Nevertheless, the restriction of the principle to sets of reals (among other general instances) is provable without the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 17):

The [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101253/surjectivity-of-operators-on-ell-infty) whether there is a non surjective bounded linear operator on $\ell_\infty$ that has dense range was answered in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.1443) by Amir Bahman Nasseri, Gideon Schechtman, Tomasz Tkocz, and me. An interesting aspect of the proof is that it uses a theorem proved by computer scientists to get a counterexample.  So, in some sense, this question about operators on a non separable Banach space is connected to computer science!

Answer (score 16):

As acknowledged in my note [Explicit additive decomposition of norms on $\mathbb{R}^2$](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.00537), it was sparked by answers by Noam D. Elkies and Suvrit Sra on MathOverflow [Absolute value inequality for complex numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/167685/absolute-value-inequality-for-complex-numbers) and Bill Johnson’s comments there. Part of the note also used the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/208194/an-inequality-for-two-independent-identically-distributed-random-vectors-in-a-no/208245#208250) by Bill Johnson to a related question posted by me.

Comment: Now published in *Amer. Math. Monthly*, May 2016, vol.123, no.5 pp.491-496.

Answer (score 15):

I am frequently asked whether exponentials are "linearly independent". That is if we have
a sequence of distinct complex numbers $\lambda_j$, whether
$$\sum_{j} a_j\exp(\lambda_j z)\equiv 0$$
implies that all $a_j=0$. If the linear dependence above holds in all complex plane, this
question was answered by A. F. Leontjev. All his books exist only in Russian, but I was asked
this question so frequently that I wrote a short note, Linear independence of exponentials,
explaining Leontjev's results, and posted it on Internet.

Then a question was asked on MO,
[On linear independence of exponentials](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31458/on-linear-independence-of-exponentials/108547#108547),
what if the linear dependence relation holds only for real $z$ (the $\lambda_j$ and $a_j$ are still complex). I could not find an answer in Leontjev's
papers, and the result was a preprint
[https://www.math.purdue.edu/~eremenko/dvi/exp2.pdf](https://www.math.purdue.edu/%7Eeremenko/dvi/exp2.pdf)

Answer (score 14):

1. In my paper [*Invariant curves and semiconjugacies of rational functions*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6552) [Fund. Math. 219 (2012), no. 3, 263–270; [MR3001243](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3001243); [DOI:10.4064/fm219-3-5](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/fm219-3-5)], I proved a theorem characterizing Jordan analytic invariant curves
   of rational functions or certain type. My theorem implies that all such curves must be algebraic, but there was no examples except circles. I asked on Overflow whether there are
   any other examples, there was no answer for some time, then I offered a bounty.

The required examples were constructed by Peter Mueller. By that time my paper was already
published, and I could not mention these examples in it, but Peter promised to
include them in his own paper [Decompositions of rational functions over real and complex numbers and a question about invariant curves](https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.07336).

[Circles and rational functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103949/circles-and-rational-functions)

2. When I asked this question  [*"Analytic function avoiding elements of the modular group"*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120369/analytic-function-avoiding-elements-of-the-modular-group), I was working on a problem about Painleve VI. The answer was very illuminating, and eventually led to a solution of my problem on Painleve VI, which resulted in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.04694), where I acknowledge the MO discussion.

Comment: I will add at least in a comment [eudml link](https://eudml.org/doc/283022) and [arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6552v3) - simply because the paper (or the preprint) is accessible here without needing any type of subscription.

Comment: Thanks. I added the link.

Answer (score 14):

The analog of the famous law of iterated logarithm for maximum eigenvalue of a random Gaussian matrix was asked  [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142371/laws-of-iterated-logarithm-for-random-matrices-and-random-permutation). [Zeitouni's MO-answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/142405/1532) was expanded (after significant effort) to a full answer for the limsup (including constants) and a partial answer for the liminf by Elliot Paquette and Ofer Zeitouni [arxiv.org/abs/1505.05627](http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.05627) !

Answer (score 14):

Keith Kearnes, together with co-authors Emil Kiss and Ágnes Szendrei, recently published a solution to [Varieties where every algebra is free](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/157974/varieties-where-every-algebra-is-free) in this [arxiv preprint](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.03807v1.pdf). They prove a result under an even weaker hypothesis: that "a variety of algebras whose finitely generated members are free must be definitionally equivalent to the variety of sets, the variety of pointed sets, a variety of vector spaces over a division ring, or a variety of affine vector spaces over a division ring".

Comment: Minor clarification: it later turned out that the title question had been answered by Steven Givant in his 1975 thesis. So the novelty in the the arxiv preprint is the weakening of the hypothesis, which was suggested as an afterthought in the MO question.

Answer (score 14):

A nice question by Michael Hardy, [How many rearrangements must fail to alter the value of a sum before you conclude that none do?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214728/how-many-rearrangements-must-fail-to-alter-the-value-of-a-sum-before-you-conclud), led to a recent 6-author collaboration, 5 or 6 of whom are MO patrons if I'm not mistaken.

- A. Blass, J. Brendle, W. Brian, J.D. Hamkins, M. Hardy, and P.B. Larson, *[The rearrangement number](http://jdh.hamkins.org/the-rearrangement-number/)* (manuscript under review).

See also this answer by Joel David Hamkins, https://mathoverflow.net/a/214779/2926, for more information. Please update this answer, Joel David, when this is published in a journal!

Comment: I receive some AMS email alerts and just noticed some familiar MO names (otherwise I probably wouldn't have opened the article). It looks like the paper is now available in Transaction of the AMS at https://doi.org/10.1090/tran/7881 and references the original question (and the question links back to this meta post).

Answer (score 13):

The paper [Quartic graphs with every edge in a triangle](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.0081) by Florian Pfender and Gordon Royle grew out of the MO question [4-regular graphs with every edge in a triangle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/84783/4-regular-graphs-with-every-edge-in-a-triangle).

Answer (score 13):

This [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/161998/is-this-hankel-matrix-in-trace-class) was the starting point for a joint work with Tao Mei where we study radial multipliers on the von Neumann algebras of hyperbolic groups. The paper is entitled Complete boundedness of the Heat Semigroups on the von Neumann Algebra of hyperbolic groups, and as the title suggests it contains among other a proof that, to our surprise, the heat semigroup, although not positive, is bounded on the von Neumann algebras of hyperbolic groups. The [arXiv version is here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.5178), and it will soon appear in Transactions of the AMS.

Answer (score 11):

According to Christian Stump, his paper "[On a New Collection of Words in the Catalan Family](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL17/Stump/stump4.html)" (*Journal of Integer Sequences*, vol. 17 (2014), article 14.7.1) is a long version of [his](https://mathoverflow.net/a/131767/12357) [answers](https://mathoverflow.net/a/132013/12357) to a MathOverflow [question asked by Vince Vatter](https://mathoverflow.net/q/131585/12357) and to a follow-up [question asked by David Speyer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/131809/12357).

Answer (score 11):

The MO question, "[Shortest closed curve to inspect a sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/q/69099/6094)," 
was cited as the "initial stimulus" for the paper

> Mohammad Ghomi, "The length, width,and inradius of space curves,"
>   ([PDF download](http://people.math.gatech.edu/~ghomi/Papers/inradius.pdf).)

He establishes a lowerbound of $6\sqrt{3}$ on the shortest inspection
curve, more than $80$% of the conjectured $4 \pi$ lowerbound.

Comment: In a subsequent paper coauthored with James Wenk, which appeared in Crelle's journal, the optimal bound $4\pi$ was obtained to settle Zalgaller's baseball curve conjecture.

Answer (score 11):

In 2013 [John Pardon](https://mathoverflow.net/users/35353/john-pardon) [solved](https://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2013-26-03/S0894-0347-2013-00766-3/) the [Hilbert-Smith conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert-Smith_conjecture) for group actions on 3-manifolds.
Lemma 2.17 of the paper was based on the answer to [this mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74799/incompressible-surfaces-in-an-open-subset-of-r3/74935#74935). I was quite surprised to receive an e-mail a few months after answering the question with a preprint resolving the conjecture, especially since I did not know the identity of the MO user (at the time he had a generic account name) or for what purpose the question was intended.

Answer (score 11):

[Mohammad Ghomi answered](https://mathoverflow.net/a/375199/6094)
the question
[Shortest closed curve to inspect a sphere](https://mathoverflow.net/q/69099/6094),
in a paper, *Shortest closed curve to inspect a sphere*, posted to the arXiv (https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.15204),
whose [PDF is available here](https://ghomi.math.gatech.edu/Papers/sphere.pdf),
verifying the conjecture that the shortest curve is four
consecutive semicircles each of length $\pi$ for a unit sphere.

Comment: I think you might have mentioned Ghomi's work twice in this same thread? https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/2866/11540

Comment: @DavidWhite: Ghomi wrote two papers on the topic separated by ~5 yrs.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know

Answer (score 10):

Stefan Kiefer and Björn Wachter just published a paper,
"Stability and Complexity of Minimising Probabilistic Automata"
([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.6673)),
which acknowledges the MO question
[convex polyhedron in the unit cube](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132262/convex-polyhedron-in-the-unit-cube).

Answer (score 10):

The question, "[How hard is reconstructing a permutation from its differences sequence?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/135968/6094)" posed by Mohammad Al-Turkistany,
was [answered by
Marzio De Biasi](https://mathoverflow.net/a/138076/6094),
who then wrote a paper, "Permutation Reconstruction from Differences,"
published in the [Electronic Journal of Combinatorics](https://doi.org/10.37236/4086) (2014):

> We prove that the problem of reconstructing a permutation $\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_n$ of the integers $[1\ldots n]$ given the absolute differences $|\pi_{i+1}-\pi_i|$, $i=1,\ldots,n−1$, is -complete.

Answer (score 10):

The answer to the question [Length of Hirzebruch continued fractions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/111312/length-of-hirzebruch-continued-fractions) was published as a short note [On continued fractions of equal length](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=dvmg&paperid=276&option_lang=eng) .

Answer (score 10):

The full answer to the question [Decidability of diophantine equation in a theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194491) by rainmaker in the case of Robinson’s arithmetic was written up in my paper [*Division by zero*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.07309), Archive for Mathematical Logic 55 (2016), no. 7, pp. 997–1013.

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if my recent paper *"[Equivalence: an attempt at a history of the idea](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11229-018-1674-2)"* qualifies as one of the "best of Mathoverflow or papers inspired by Mathoverflow". But I am sure Mathoverflow was a force to keep me motivated for a journey that started 13 years ago into the long and rich history of equivalence.

It was 4 years and 6 months ago that I asked on MO: *["Who introduced the terms “equivalence relation” and “equivalence class”?"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135347/who-introduced-the-terms-equivalence-relation-and-equivalence-class/135375#135375)* When I asked the question I was kind of full of myself to know nearly every corner of the relevant history, and the question was kind of let me find even that bit that I don't know. But, suddenly, there it was @Francois Ziegler's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/135375/29316) and then his comment to my own [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/135635/29316). Wow, it was much more than I asked. Basically, it opened up my eyes to something in front of me all the times, but I had failed to see it all the times. That answer was a new beginning for something that had started 6 years and a half year ago and continued for another 4 years and a half year!
The paper has been dedicated to David Fowler for the reasons mentioned in the paper and [here](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3598/29316) (link to meta-MO post). But, I believe both Fowler and I should thank Francois for his short enlightening answer. Here is the abstract of the paper, hoping it deserves the name of David Fowler, Christopher Zeeman, Jeremy Gray, and Francois Ziegler who directly or indirectly, knowingly or unknowingly, encouraged me to finish my journey.

> This paper proposes a reading of the history of equivalence in
>   mathematics. The paper has two main parts. The first part focuses on a
>   relatively short historical period when the notion of equivalence is
>   about to be decontextualized, but yet, has no commonly agreed-upon
>   name. The method for this part is rather straightforward: following
>   the clues left by the others for the ‘first’ modern use of
>   equivalence. The second part focuses on a relatively long historical
>   period when equivalence is experienced in context. The method for this
>   part is to strip the ideas from their set-theoretic formulations and
>   methodically examine the variations in the ways equivalence appears in
>   some prominent historical texts. The paper reveals several critical
>   differences in the conceptions of equivalence at different points in
>   history that are at variance with the standard account of the
>   mathematical notion of equivalence encompassing the concepts of
>   equivalence relation and equivalence class.

Answer (score 10):

An unpublished open problem posed by Adam Chalcraft, [Does every polyomino tile $\mathbb R^n$ for some $n$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/49915/3106), received considerable attention when I posted it here on MO. (Of all the questions that I have posed on MO that aren't soft questions, it has received the most upvotes—69 as of this writing.)  It was solved by Vytautas Gruslys, Imre Leader, and Ta Sheng Tan, who learned about it from MO, in

> Vytautas, Gruslys, Imre Leader, Ta Sheng Tan, *Tiling with arbitrary tiles*, Proc. Lond. Math. Soc. (3) **112** No. 6 (2016) 1019–1039, doi:[10.1112/plms/pdw017](https://doi.org/10.1112/plms/pdw017), arXiv:[1505.03697](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.03697)

Comment: And just to close the loop: They provided a positive answer.

Answer (score 10):

Hannah Cairns's proof of Perron's theorem (discussed in this [MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/292582/12357)) has been published in The American Mathematical Monthly as *[Perron’s Theorem in an Hour](https://doi.org/10.1080/00029890.2021.1944755)*.

Answer (score 9):

This paper,

> Roman Karasev, Jan Kynčl, Pavel Paták, Zuzana Safernová, and Martin Tancer. "Bounds for Pach's selection theorem and for the minimum solid angle in a simplex." [arXiv:1403.8147](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.8147) (2014).
>   *Discrete & Computational Geometry*. **54**:610-636 (2015).

cites [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/53881/6094) to Boris Bukh's
question,
[Angle of a regular simplex](https://mathoverflow.net/q/53872/6094),
in the discussion of their theorem giving an upper bound on the minimum solid
angle of a $d$-simplex.

Incidentally, they pose a very nice question:

> Is it true that the minimum solid
>   angle of a $d$-simplex is at most the solid angle of a regular $d$-simplex?

The answer is *Yes* for $d \le 4$.

Comment: In context, they write "This shows that our bound in
Theorem 6 is tight up to lower order terms in the exponent. Rogers’ proof is also reproduced
in a book by Zong [Zon99, Lemma 7.2]. We have learnt about this from an answer of Joseph
O’Rourke [O’R11] to a question of Boris Bukh at MathOverflow."

Answer (score 9):

Julien Marché's question  [*"Homology generated by lifts of simple curves"*](https://mathoverflow.net/q/86894/) was the first appearance in print of a folklore question (I first was asked it back when I was a postdoc).  As I discuss in my answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/278110/), there have been a number of recent papers addressing it, including

J. Malestein, A. Putman, Simple closed curves, finite covers of surfaces, and power subgroups of $\text{Out}(F_n)$, preprint 2017.

T. Koberda, R. Santharoubane, Quotients of surface groups and homology of finite covers via quantum representations, Invent. Math. 206 (2016), no. 2, 269–292.

B. Farb, S. Hensel, Finite covers of graphs, their primitive homology, and representation theory, New York J. Math. 22 (2016), 1365–1391.

Answer (score 8):

Shengkui Ye, in the review in Math Reviews of Bela Bauer and Claire Levaillant, A new set of generators and a physical interpretation for the SU(3) finite subgroup D(9,1,1;2,1,1), Quantum Inf. Process. 12 (2013), no. 7, 2509–2521, MR3065503, cites the discussion at [The finite subgroups of SU(n)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17072/the-finite-subgroups-of-sun) as contradicting the claim by Bauer and Levaillant that "After 100 years of effort, the classification of all the finite subgroups of SU(3) is yet incomplete.''

Answer (score 8):

[Joachim König](https://mathsci.kaist.ac.kr/%7Ejkoenig/) has answered my question
[Order of products of elements in symmetric groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118092/order-of-products-of-elements-in-symmetric-groups)
in his paper [A note on the product of two permutations of prescribed orders](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.02170),
to appear in *European Journal of Combinatorics*.

Answer (score 8):

My [Forum of Mathematics Sigma](https://doi.org/10.1017/fms.2021.58) paper (published 2021) answered a 20-year old question of Jeff Shallit. The proof makes crucial use of ideas in [a 2016 MO answer by Anthony Quas](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/247884/longest-runs-and-concentration-of-measure/247929#247929).

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Thanks @Andrés!

Answer (score 7):

Yoav Kallus gave interesting improvement in [“The Two Sheriffs” puzzle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203182/the-two-sheriffs-puzzle). It is not a serious open problem but he gave a really surprizing [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203182/the-two-sheriffs-puzzle/203270#203270) using Fano plane.

Answer (score 7):

[Leonardo Zapponi](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eleonardo.zapponi/Web2/index.html) has answered my question
[Parametric solutions of Pell's equation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194910/parametric-solutions-of-pells-equation)
in his paper [Parametric solutions of Pell equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00637).

Answer (score 7):

The discussion initiated by my question
[Primes occurring as orders of elements of a finitely presented group](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121178/primes-occurring-as-orders-of-elements-of-a-finitely-presented-group)
led to the addition of Section 5 to:

[Maurice Chiodo](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/%7Emcc56/), [*On torsion in finitely presented groups*](https://doi.org/10.1515/gcc-2014-0001),
Groups Complexity Cryptology 6(1): 1-8 (2014). [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.1489).

Answer (score 7):

This [paper of mine](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.05740) (Arithmetic Restrictions on Geometric Monodromy) was inspired in large part by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/190530/are-there-nonisotrivial-elliptic-curves-over-mathbbg-m) asked by [Lisa S.](https://mathoverflow.net/users/63877/lisa-s), though the original motivation is not so obvious in the final product.

Answer (score 7):

The paper [*"Majority colourings of digraphs"*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.03040) by Paul Seymour, Stephan Kreutzer, Sang-il Oum, David R. Wood and myself has its origin in my question [*"Majority coloring for directed graphs"*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/233014/majority-coloring-for-directed-graphs).

Comment: American spelling for MO, British for arXiv?

Comment: That's right, we had to upgrade the spelling from MO to arXiv :)

Answer (score 7):

This paper addresses and partially solves a question posed by Matthew Kahle, 
whose MO question they explicitly cite:
[chromatic number of the hyperbolic plane](https://mathoverflow.net/q/86234/6094).

> DeCorte, Evan, and Konstantin Golubev. "Lower bounds for the measurable chromatic number of the hyperbolic plane." *Discrete & Computational Geometry* 62, no. 2 (2019): 481-496.
>   [Journal link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00454-018-0027-8).

"Using spectral methods, we prove that if the colour classes are measurable, then at least six colours are needed to properly colour   $\mathbb{H}(d)$ when $d$ is sufficiently large."

Answer (score 7):

Quoting [Oscar Cunningham's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/345392) to an MO question asking for decision problems that are not known to be decidable:

> In Conway's Game of Life, the problem of deciding whether a given pattern with finitely many live cells is a Garden of Eden (i.e. whether it lacks a predecessor).
>
> **Added 2019 December 3:** Having learnt about the problem from this post, Ville Salo and Ilkka Törmä have produced a paper ([Gardens of Eden in the Game of Life](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.00692)) showing that this problem is decidable.

Comment: You might review the post, as some part of the problem is open, and your excerpt does not reflect that.  Gerhard "Let's Not Do False Advertising" Paseman, 2019.12.03.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman : What I've written here looks correct to me.  I intentionally omitted the extra open problem that Oscar Cunningham introduced, as a potential road to proving the main open problem that was ultimately not used by Salo and Törmä. Do you see something wrong?

Comment: Yes, but it is probably my misunderstanding (or misperception) of the problem.  If you exercised your customary due diligence, then I don't think you need to change it.  My impression was that they (the authors of the paper) had only solved a decision problem of whether a finite configuration had a finite predecessor, not the decision problem of whether it had a predecessor.  Gerhard "Maybe I'm Mixing Up Quantifiers?" Paseman, 2019.12.03.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman : Let C1 = "there exists an algorithm for deciding whether a given pattern with finitely many live cells is a Garden of Eden" and let C2 = "there is no non-Garden-of-Eden with finitely many live cells all of whose predecessors have infinitely many live cells." C1 is the main question of interest, which is now proved. Cunningham pointed out that C2 implies C1, but Salo and Törmä's proof of C1 did not go by way of C2, which remains open.

Comment: Ah. For the careful reader, there may be no need to mention C2. For the casual reader (which seems to be me more often lately, but might also be students reading your post), your comment about C2 adds much to understanding.  I leave it to you whether to include the comment material in the post above. I strongly recommend leaving your comment for future readers. Gerhard "Learns Much From Reading Comments" Paseman, 2019.12.03.

Answer (score 7):

This doesn't quite fit the mold of the other postings, but Matt Parker
([Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/user/numberphile)
and StandUpMaths)
made
a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yq3P-LhlcQo&ab_channel=Stand-upMaths)
that mentions MathOverflow
several times, and particularly highlights the work of
[Moritz Firsching](https://mathoverflow.net/q/300713/6094).

[image: MattParker]

Comment: Such a fun video!

Answer (score 6):

The paper, "A quantitative obstruction to collapsing surfaces," by Mikahil G. Katz,
[arXiv abs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.06782), addresses the MO question, "[Gromov-Hausdorff limits of 2-dimensional Riemannian surfaces](https://mathoverflow.net/q/236001/6094)" posed by *sva* (S. Alesker).

> **Abstract**. We provide a quantitative obstruction to collapsing surfaces of genus at least $2$ under a lower curvature bound and an upper diameter bound.

Answer (score 6):

[This MO question *"Property $\Gamma$ in terms of correspondences"*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/323219/property-gamma-in-terms-of-correspondences) led us to answer two old open problems and to push further a third more recent result:

*Jon Bannon, Amine Marrakchi, Narutaka Ozawa. Full factors and co-amenable inclusions*, [arxiv/1903.05395](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.05395).

Thanks MO!!!

Comment: push? publish??

Comment: I think it wouldn't hurt to edit in links to whatever you have written up (if your results are ready for publication).

Comment: I see. Taka linked to the paper in the comment following his answer, which set this in motion. I'll link to the paper in the answer here...

Answer (score 6):

Garabed Gulbenkian's 2010 [question about ordinal definable real numbers](https://mathoverflow.net/q/17608), which Joel David Hamkins called "a fascinating, outstanding question," attracted considerable attention, culminating in a 2015 paper by Kanovei and Lyubetsky, [A definable ${\mathsf E}_0$ class containing no definable elements](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00153-015-0436-9).  The paper credits MathOverflow as the source of the question (although, curiously, Gulbenkian is not mentioned by name).

Answer (score 6):

I just learned that a question of mine on [minimal vertex covers in hypergraphs where edges intersect in at most $1$ point](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277856/minimal-covering-sets-in-families-of-sets-intersecting-in-at-most-1-point) led to a [paper](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0012365X22004861?token=607B1A50CDA47F29125C269487FCABE311DCB68A81DBD63E0641E2190CAA78097D1711E7C21DF9B80D5B5B8375159757&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20221209134804) by [Lajos Soukup](https://mathoverflow.net/users/71011/lajos-soukup) and Tamas Csernak; it will appear in Discrete Mathematics in 2023. The paper [does not fully answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/436215/8628) the original question - but congratulations are in order to Lajos and Tamas for their progress.

Answer (score 6):

Zhi-Wei Sun posted a highly upvoted MO question in 2018, [Can we write each positive rational number as ${1\over p_1−1}+\cdots+{1\over p_k−1}$ with $p_1,\ldots,p_k$ distinct primes?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/316474) The question remained without an answer until May 2023, when Thomas Bloom posted an answer to MO and a preprint to the arXiv (though the preprint does not mention MathOverflow).

Answer (score 5):

Ilya Bogdanov has answered my question [*Graphs with only disjoint perfect matchings*](https://mathoverflow.net/a/267013/63938)
 on certain coloring in graphs, that emerged through research in quantum physics. This answer has inspired quite a bit of research:

- [Quantum Experiments and Graphs](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.119.240403) ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.06646) - cited Bogdanov's MO answer)
- [Quantum experiments and graphs II](https://www.pnas.org/content/116/10/4147.abstract) ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.10736))
- [Quantum experiments and graphs. III](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.99.032338) ([arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.09558) - cited Bogdanov's MO answer)

Furthermore in [Questions on the Structure of Perfect Matchings inspired by Quantum Physics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.06023), we generalize the question on inherited colorings to cover the full potential of quantum physics. One of my co-authors is [Daniel Soltész](https://mathoverflow.net/users/38267/daniel-solt%C3%A9sz), who I only met through MO. In this paper we cited Bogdanov's MO answere again (and called it "Bogdanov's Lemma").

The Q1 of the article is another MO question[*"Vertex coloring inherited from perfect matchings (motivated by quantum physics)"*](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/311325/vertex-coloring-inherited-from-perfect-matchings-motivated-by-quantum-physics), but i have little hope that I get so lucky again.

This is certainly, *by far*, my personal "Best of MO".

Answer (score 4):

I [asked a somewhat silly question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/143947/3948), which silliness was pointed out by [Tobias Fritz](https://mathoverflow.net/a/143950/3948), which [answer I cited](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.4833375) just to be pedantic about a point in set theory in a paper I wrote recently.

Answer (score 4):

A paper by T. Chartier, P.P. Pach and myself describing the status of "[Can we color Z^+ with n colors such that a, 2a, …, na all have different colors for all a?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/26358/6085)" has just been published.

*Coloring the $n$-Smooth Numbers with $n$ Colors*, The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics **28 (1)** (2021), #P1.34. https://doi.org/10.37236/8492

Answer (score 4):

In response to an MO question, [On maximal regular polyhedra inscribed in a regular polyhedron](https://mathoverflow.net/q/138229/6094),
Moritz Firsching [filled in the missing cases](https://mathoverflow.net/a/154007/6094)
from H.T. Crofts original paper on the topic.

He then posted a paper to the arXiv in 2014,
"Computing maximal copies of polytopes contained in a polytope."
[arXiv abstract](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.0683),
and it was published in 2015 in
*Experimental Mathematics* Vol. 24 (2015), Issue 1, pp.98-105.

Answer (score 4):

Beginning with [discussions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179108/is-the-sequence-of-ap%C3%A9ry-numbers-a-stieltjes-moment-sequence) in MO, it was proved that the Apéry sequence is a Stieltjes moment sequence.  My final streamlined argument for this was posted to the arxiv in 2020:
[LINK](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.10733)

Answer (score 3):

Another candidate for this thread of Mathoverflow success stories: my recent [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/358996/1898) to [Finding the nearest matrix with real eigenvalues](https://mathoverflow.net/q/273669/1898).

From the answer:

> We started our research by thinking about this problem, but then we were happily surprised to find out that the technique can be applied also to a harder problem that had already been studied in the literature on numerical linear algebra and control theory, that of finding the nearest Hurwitz stable matrix. And, more generally, it can be extended to solve numerically the problem of finding
>   $$
> B = \arg \min_{S_\Omega} \|B-A\|_F,
> $$
>   where $S_\Omega$ is the set of all (real or complex) matrices with all eigenvalues in a given closed set $\Omega$. Another nice example of how procrastinating and thinking about Mathoverflow questions can lead to useful research sometimes. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here are two kind-of dual results that have now been proved after I asked them here:

The first arose from [Induced map on path manifolds: is it a submersion?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/85960/induced-map-on-path-manifolds-is-it-a-submersion/132937#132937), which got an answer in very general terms involving generalised smooth spaces in this preprint:

- Andrew Stacey, *Yet More Smooth Mapping Spaces and Their Smoothly Local Properties*, arXiv:[1301.5493](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.5493).

and then again in this paper, as Lemma 2.4:

- Habib Amiri, Alexander Schmeding *A differentiable monoid of smooth maps on Lie groupoids*, Journal of Lie Theory **29** (2019), No. 4, 1167–1192, arXiv:[1706.04816](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.04816)

in a way that only partially overlaps with Andrew Stacey's version; in one sense it's less general, but it seems to use a stronger notion of submersion/regular map.

The second came from [Extension of functions from geodesically convex compact sets in a Riemannian manifold](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235971/extension-of-functions-from-geodesically-convex-compact-sets-in-a-riemannian-man), which has now been answered in

- David Michael Roberts, Alexander Schmeding, *Extending Whitney's extension theorem: nonlinear function spaces*, to appear, Annales de l'Institut Fourier, arXiv:[1801.04126](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.04126)

---

A different kind of question I asked now has three papers giving three different approaches, namely [On a weak choice principle](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/73921/on-a-weak-choice-principle), which led to (in chronological order):

- Benno van den Berg, *WISC is independent of ZF*, ([pdf](https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/b.vandenberg3/papers/WISC.pdf)), also Theorem 5.1/Corollary 5.2 in *Predicative toposes*, arXiv:[1207.0959](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0959). This uses Gitik's class forcing symmetric model of ZF, over ZFC with a reasonably strong large cardinal assumption.
- Asaf Karagila, *Embedding Orders Into Cardinals With $DC_\kappa$*, Fund. Math. **226** (2014), 143-156, doi:[10.4064/fm226-2-4](http://doi.org/10.4064/fm226-2-4), arXiv:[1212.4396](http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4396). This uses class forcing symmetric models, over ZFC with no large cardinals.
- David Michael Roberts, *The weak choice principle WISC may fail in the category of sets*, Studia Logica Volume **103** (2015) Issue 5, pp 1005-1017, doi:[10.1007/s11225-015-9603-6](http://doi.org/10.1007/s11225-015-9603-6) arXiv:[1311.3074](http://arxiv.org/abs/1311.3074). This uses topos-theoretic methods, over a well-pointed base topos with no Choice.

Answer (score -4):

This [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.03735) of Souvik Dey (on commutative ring theory) cites an MO post.