# Answer to what was an open question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I vaguely remember reading a question on main about a possibly "open question", which got an answer which started by affirming that the question is indeed open, and then proceeded to provide a solution to the open question, making it no longer open by the end of the answer.

I was specifically thinking about this because if I remember correctly it is an example of an open question being solved as a corollary of some (later) bigger results, and that no-one until the answerer noticed that the open question can be solved in that manner.

Unfortunately I remember none of the useful information that actually can help me search for the question/answer. In particular I know not what subject this was in, nor who the answerer was! Does the above description ring a bell for anyone?

Comment: Was it the post of Mark Sapir here? http://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/618/2926

Comment: Though you have already got your answer, I thougt it is worth mentioning this meta post http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/617/best-of-mathoverflow, that is a collection of successful MO stories, including the one you were interested in.

Comment: @AmirAsghari: you may have failed to notice that _that_ link was exactly the one Todd posted one comment above. `:-)` He linked to the relevant answer in the thread, while you linked to the question.

Comment: Oops :) It is @Todd fault, linking to two diffenent places! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hah, my "trivial answer" was converted to a comment. Anyway, you may have been thinking of Mark Sapir's post, as more appropriately linked to here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/137715/2926.

Comment: That's it! Thanks.

Comment: Even though this is not directly related -- 
Mark Sapir has stated *"Most probably I won’t be active on mathoverflow.net any longer:
too many homework level questions and the community attitude towards these questions 
has become too liberal."* -- see http://marksapir.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/mathoverflow/ .

Comment: @StefanKohl Hm, not sure what he means, since we seem to spend a lot of time closing such questions. Or perhaps I would say he has too liberal an attitude of what constitutes 'homework'.

Comment: @ToddTrimble: I can't tell for sure as well -- just thought it worth to provide the link, without attempting to interpret.