# Examples of mathematical exposition arising from MO answers

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, big-list

I could imagine that several very long Mathoverflow answers have eventually turned into expository papers. For example, I have posted [this (unpublished) expository paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.6086.pdf) on the arxiv about various notions of zero-dimensionality as a response to a MO question. What are some examples of some answers to Mathoverflow questions which have eventually grown into expository papers or other forms of mathematical exposition (such as a section in a textbook or even a piece of software)?

In [this question](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/617/best-of-mathoverflow?page=1&tab=active#tab-top), people gave examples of good original research that has arisen from mathoverflow answers, but I want to now see examples of published mathematical exposition which have arisen as the result of Mathoverflow answers.

Answer (score 12):

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0202)  resulted from a question on mathoverflow. This monograph on properties of 3-manifold groups has now [appeared in print](http://dx.doi.org/10.4171/154).

Comment: Do you know which question specifically? Among the MO questions that left a "trackback / blog link" to the arxiv page, only these two were asked before the survey was posted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/32292 http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63321 and the first seems a likely candidate. I couldn't find it in the paper itself since MO is not explicitly cited there. (However, the authors thank Anton Geraschenko for bringing them together -- is that a veiled reference to MO?)

Comment: It might be one of those questions, or this question, which was asked by Stefan Friedl and answered by Henry Wilton: http://mathoverflow.net/q/15121/1345 In any case, I'm not exactly sure, but I think one of them told me that the collaboration started via mathoverflow (and I think that's the reference in the paper to Anto Geraschenko).

Answer (score 9):

[The note "Did a 1-dimensional magnet detect a 248-dimensional Lie algebra?"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.5407) by David Borthwick and Skip Garibaldi mentioned in [this MO answer by Garibaldi](https://mathoverflow.net/a/48485) was published [here](http://www.ams.org/notices/201108/rtx110801055p.pdf) in the Notices of the AMS.

Answer (score 9):

My preprint [arXiv:1609.01160](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.01160) was written in response to [Question 248665](https://mathoverflow.net/q/248665/2821).

Answer (score 3):

Many answers by Joel David Hamkins have been the inspiration behind later papers, for example "[Is the twin prime conjecture independent of Peano arithmetic?](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.08640)" is an arXiv submission that is developed from a 2012 MO answer, as detailed in Hamkins's [blog post](http://jdh.hamkins.org/is-the-twin-prime-conjecture-independent-of-peano-arithmetic/) of the same name.