# Is there a post where one can thank mathoverflow community?

Tags: discussion

Is there a post where one can thank MathOverflow community for its indirect help for a paper that has recently published, along with the link of the paper? (Especially given that MathOverflow being mentioned in the acknowledgments of the paper) Is this encouraged? What's your opinion?

Or will this be interpreted as self promotion?

**Edit**

[This post](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/617/14414) I believe does not qualify for the following reasons

The heading there suggests the papers needs to be directly inspired by a mathoverflow post, and also "best of...". I don't think my case qualifies for any of these. I am talking about the case of community indirectly helping, rather than inspiring, and also the work need not be "best of ". It need not be inspired by any particular post on mathoverflow, but author just taking indirect help by asking questions in chunks...

Comment: Have a look at https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/617/best-of-mathoverflow-or-papers-inspired-by-mathoverflow

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what else you've seen, so we don't waste our time and yours telling you things you already know.

Comment: I see that you have said thank you [in the MathOverflow chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9369/2020/6/4) - that seems like a reasonable place.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSleziak. Makes sense.

Comment: I'd select one question or one answer that was especially helpful, and post a comment there saying "thanks; this was especially helpful in writing", followed by the link. That shows people where the discussions here can go.